# CSV file matadata validation (comparing with existing SQl Table)

Tags: sql

I have a requirement of validating CSV file before loading into staged-folder, and later have to load into sql table.
I need to validate metadata (the structure of the file must be same as target sql table)
No. of columns should be equal to the target sql table
order of columns should be same as target sql table
Data types of columns (no text values should exist in numeric field of csv file)
looking for some easy and efficient way achieve this.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

A Python program and module that does most of what you're looking for is chkcsv.py: https://pypi.org/project/chkcsv/.  It can be used to verify that a CSV file contains a specified set of columns and that the data type of each column conforms to the specification.  It does not, however, verify that the order of columns in the CSV file is the same as the order in the database table.  Instead of loading the CSV file directly into the target table, you can load it into a staging table and then move it from there into the target table--this two-step process eliminates column order dependence.

Disclaimer: I wrote chkcsv.py

Edit 2020-01-26: I just added an option that allows you to specify that the column order should be checked also.

Comment: Thanks for Python program. I never worked in Python, but it's worthwhile to try this out. thanks